# BlackBerry - Question about signing, deploy and networking

Tags: web-services, networking, blackberry, code-signing

hi i have developed an j2me application, which uses these api's:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ChoiceGroup;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemStateListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.DateField;    
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;        
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;    
import javax.microedition.location.LocationException;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import java.util.Date;    
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemCommandListener;
import javax.microedition.location.Criteria;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;
import javax.microedition.location.QualifiedCoordinates;

import cbpserviceservice.CBPServiceService_Stub;
import de.enough.polish.ui.TableItem;
import de.enough.polish.calendar.CalendarItem;
import de.enough.polish.ui.Alert;
import de.enough.polish.ui.AlertType;
import de.enough.polish.ui.FramedForm;
import de.enough.polish.ui.TextBox;
```

Please let me know, if by any chance i need to sign this application.

And if not now i want to deploy the application on the device.
the application gets installed on the device, using the software blackberry desktop manager 4.7

I want to add , my appplication is accessing web services, so in the stubs generated in the code, there is the URL of the web services, so i append ;deviceside=true to the url.
as per my knowledge, now the application can make TCP calls, and does not need MDS.

but i cannot hit the server, the application is not hitting the web service.
Please let me know, where i am wrong.
and what more i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Blackberry JDE will tell you if you need signatures, and which ones. deviceSide=true with no other options selects Direct TCP connection (also known as carrier TCP). To support this the device has to have the APN correctly configured, or the APN data has to be encoded in the URL.

See [this video](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=NetworkingTransports).

Answer (score 0):

May be usefull:

[A60 How and When to Sign](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A60_How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf) (PDF): This tutorial covers 3 signature methods, as well as how to get signature keys and use them to sign your application

[A70 How to Deploy and Distribute Applications](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A70_How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf) (PDF): Learn how to deploy and distribute your BlackBerry application to end users

[BlackBerry Knowledge Base Networking articles](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=800563&objAction=browse&sort=name)

Also, test web service from blackberry browser, to be sure it's accessible from device at all